# phpbb3 external login with curl

Tags: php, curl, authentication, external, phpbb3

I have created an extension for my website. It should log in user to forum after he has logged in to the website.

User session was created successfully (checked in database), but user still not logged in.

If I try to log in with external login form, it works great (the session is created and user is logged in).

I think the problem is not in my authentication extension.

I think I did something wrong with curl post and cookie.

What curl options should I set to login? Or maybe you can give me some useful links?

Comment: curl requests will log in curl, but not the end user unless you take the cookies phpBB set with curl and set them for the client's browser.

Comment: Take some of those phpbb3_* cookies and then send them through `[setcookie()`](http://php.net/setcookie) to pass along to the user.  It might work, depending on your level of cookie security in phpBB (it can't be tied to IP because curl and the user IP will be different.

Comment: ok. will try. thanks =)

Comment: Could you help me also with another one question?

In phphbb admin panel is present "Session IP validation:" field. 
And i want leave it with ABC value.

Is there some way to set ip-address with cUrl ?

currently i'm using this
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("REMOTE_ADDR: $ip", "HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: $ip"));

Thanks again. 

P.S.
previous answer has helped me with issue. But there are another issues as you can see =)

Comment: You won't be able to use curl and pass the cookies to the client if you have Session IP validation turned on.  I'd suggest turning that off, or, instead of using curl, look for a plugin/module that can do 3rd party logins, or look at the authentication handling code and replicate it.  It wouldn't take much to log a user in without requiring their phpBB password.

Comment: thanks for your replay. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Take some of those phpbb3_* cookies and then send them through
>   [setcookie()]([php.net/setcookie](http://php.net/setcookie)) to pass along to the user. It
>   might work, depending on your level of cookie security in phpBB (it
>   can't be tied to IP because curl and the user IP will be different
>
> #### drew010
>
> You won't be able to use curl and pass the cookies to the client if you >have Session IP validation turned on. I'd suggest turning that off, or, >instead of using curl, look for a plugin/module that can do 3rd party >logins, or look at the authentication handling code and replicate it. It >wouldn't take much to log a user in without requiring their phpBB password
>
> #### drew010

Comment: What do you mean from this answer? Are you quoting from somewhere? Else avoid using Blockquotes

Comment: I wrote answers that helped me to solve my problem. 
These answers i got in comments above. I added they to blockquotes as i'm not an author of them.
Also i  wrote nickname of comment's author